# Special search problem

Tags: search, groups

I have input around 1000 contacts from a specific country. Most of these are already in groups. I want to create a group for contacts from that country that are not yet in a group. How can I do that? I could not find a way to search for them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing by using the Include / Exclude custom search (Search => Custom Searches => Include/Exclude Contacts in a Group/Tag)

Include a group that has all the contacts that you're looking at.  In your case you may need to create a smart group that has all the people in the country.  Then in the exclude list all the groups that they should be/could be assigned to.  Search.  You'll be left with all the people in the country to don't belong to any of the groups you listed in exclude.